# How to use chartkick and vue in html?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, chartkick

I have tried to use chartkick with vue.js. I used vue & vuetify here as a CDN in my laravel project. I can't use chartkick here. I don't understand how to setup. I tried like this.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('page_content')


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"   rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/vue-chartkick.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/chartkick.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/chart.min.js') }}"></script>



<div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 0px;"   >
  <v-app color="grey lighten-5" id="app">

    <line-chart :data="{'2017-01-01': 11, '2017-01-02': 6}"></line-chart>

  <v-spacer></v-spacer>

  </v-app>

</div>


<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    el: '#app',
  })
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Check this link `https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/oeXZjO`

Comment: and check this `https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartkick`